# Here is the Empty List of IOS simulators 12.1 and 12.4. How can I install them back?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

As a ios developer, i need iOS simulators so that I can build my project and dependencies using Carthage. When I run `carthage bootstrap` , I find that my iOS simluators missing. Would you please help me advise the way to install the simulators back?

```
jackson@Larrys-MBP src % xcrun simctl list devices
== Devices ==
-- iOS 10.0 --
-- iOS 10.1 --
-- iOS 10.2 --
-- iOS 10.3 --
-- iOS 11.0 --
-- iOS 12.1 --
-- iOS 12.4 --
-- tvOS 12.4 --
-- watchOS 2.2 --
-- watchOS 5.3 --
jackson@Larrys-MBP src % open -a Simulator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Xcode (e.g. Xcode 11.2.1) and open Xcode->Preferences->Components and tap "arrow down" for corresponding iOS simulators to download.

Xcode 11.2.1 allows to download simulators starting from iOS 10.3. Hence, you will need to download older version of the Xcode to be able to install previous versions, e.g. Xcode 10.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you deleted the simulator devices (either via the Devices Window in Xcode or via the simctl command line tool).  Xcode will automatically create some devices when it encounters a new simulator runtime.  If you delete them, they don't get recreated.

If you want them back, you'll need to manually recreate them using the devices window or simctl (eg: `xcrun simctl create ...`)

Comment: any examples for creating simulator by command? I need 12.4 one